# With pipewire: Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Tags: bluetooth, pipewire

On Debian with Pipewire and WirePlumber, I'm getting,

```
[MX Ergo]# connect 8C:91:09:55:1A:CA
Attempting to connect to 8C:91:09:55:1A:CA
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable
```

Previously with PulseAudio this worked. I see this will all devices,

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller BC:09:1B:DE:EC:C9 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C DCR010
[bluetooth]# pair 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C
Attempting to pair with 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C Bonded: yes
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C Modalias: usb:v099Ap0500d011B
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C
Attempting to connect to 08:EB:ED:77:70:5C
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur due to the [`libspa-0.2-bluetooth`](https://packages.debian.org/libspa-0.2-bluetooth) package not being installed.

If this is the case, you may want to install the [`pipewire-audio`](https://packages.debian.org/pipewire-audio) package which "depends on a recommended set of pipewire packages for a standard audio desktop use", including [`libspa-0.2-bluetooth`](https://packages.debian.org/libspa-0.2-bluetooth).